# Individual subscriptions at template-level, how bad am I abusing template-level subscriptions?

Tags: meteor, handlebarshelper

I've gotten lazy and added the following helper:

```
// Given a userId, show the username
Handlebars.registerHelper('username', function(userId) {
    // This seems extremely wasteful
    Template.instance().subscribe('user', userId);

    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId });
    if (user) {
        return user.username;
    }   
    return "";
});
```

Yay for template-level subscriptions, works great for my prototype! I couldn't find anybody denouncing the idea, but maybe that's because it's so stupid that nobody would consider doing it. Do you have experience with this pattern, and can you recommend it?

I'm worried about the amount of subscriptions specifically, and about the extensive re-rendering they might cause.

Comment: Well, at least it works. If you have a list of 50 unique user ids I wouldn't recommend it though (would create 50 different subscriptions!).

Comment: Yeah, the question is how bad it is to start 50 subscriptions while the template is being rendered :-)

Comment: I don't know how bad it is (it sounds pretty bad to me), but if I were you, I would instead try to attach the usernames to the docs you're getting the users' ids from. Sure, duplicating data this way is bad, but it's a trade off. Hopefully someone else can give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Its an extremely powerful and useful feature for complex layouts, but it really shouldn't be used in this way.   While Meteor can offer you super powers, if you don't implement them with care, you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, this isnt the smartest thing to do. Why reinvent the wheel when you
already have this kind of helper defined.

```
{{currentUser}}
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser

Need username ... `{{currentUser.username}}`

Comment: That only works for the current user. From his code it seems like he want it to work for arbitrary user.

Comment: The only usage of this code I can think of is when Id be listing users or posts or whatever and wanted to get the user name (owner name).

Comment: I need to display usernames all over the place and the previous solution was to extract all user ID on template load and subscribe to the list. What I'm doing here is easier but it might not scale, so I'm asking about that.

Comment: I suspect this scales just fine, since a subscription just subscribes to a collection. Multiple subscriptions on the same collection, whether they overlap or not, does not cause the same data to be fetched from the server multiple times. Meteor is smart!

Comment: @SandervandenAkker, the more subscriptions you have, the more work will the server do. Figuring out which data is duplicate or not takes time.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the general helper probably isn't that bad, but I would separate the subscription and the name retrieval to have the subscription run only once:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('userSubscribe', function(userIds) { // make userIds an array
    Template.instance().subscribe('users', userIds); // change your publishing function to take the array
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('userName', function(userId) { 
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId });
    if (user) {
        return user.username;
    }   
    return "";
});
```

Each template is then responsible for sending the list of users it actually wants to subscribe to.  Let's assume you have a posts collection that has, for simplicity, the following format:

```
{author: user_id, commenter: user_id, text: String}
```

Then you should be able to use it like so:

```
// JS
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  getMyUsers: function() { return [this.author, this.commenter]; }
});

// HTML
<template name='myTemplate'>
  {{userSubscribe getMyUsers}}
  The author is {{userName author}} and the commenter is {{userName commenter}}
</template>
```

It's probably still not ideal, but it should re-render only once rather than for each user whose name you want to look up when the data reaches the client.

Comment: Yes I did something similar before I got lazy :-)